# How can I make a pop-up window in Polymer Project?

Tags: popup, polymer, window, project

I want to add an additional note in my app and I want to use pop-up window but I can't find a specific element for this action.

Comment: Can you please provide a specific code example of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're after a popup dialog.

Polymer 0.5: https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/paper-dialog.html

Polymer 0.9: https://github.com/polymerelements/paper-dialog